# auto search suggest with three text fields and displaying three columns paralal in the display panel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I Need Search line where i can search from three dissfrenc text boxes  and displaying three columns link in this image. i am using php, jquery JavaScript and ajax mysql to make this [image]

bt i is working with only one text (1st box) box simultenously.

plz help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

for example...

```
  $sql = "select * from Firmname";
        if($materiaux != '')
        $sql.= " where Firmnamelike '".mysql_real_escape_string($Firmname)."%'";
        $sql .= " order by FirmnameASC  ";
        $result = $this->sqlQueryArray($sql);
        return $result;
```

//In ajax,

```
if(trim($Firmname) != '')
                $final_result   = ucfirst(($Firmname))."|".$Firmname_id."|".$PersonName."|".$MobileNO;
            $final_result   .= "\n";
            echo $final_result;
```

Comment: sir can u send me complete example